# Help identifying this pink flowering plant native to Denmark

Tags: identification, houseplants

I would like help identifying this pink flowering plant that I was told is native to Denmark. It has leaves that almost look like geraniums and flower stamins that reminiscent to hibiscus or rose of sharons. The petals are pink and quite delicate, almost like a cross between a sweet pea and a rose of sharon.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well it's the mallow family, so a [Lavatera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavatera), but as to which variety, I'm not at all sure. Tree mallows become woody shrubs, but there is also [*Lavatera trimestris*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavatera_trimestris) and its many cultivars, which are annuals. Native to Europe.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an [Alcea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcea). That one doesn't look exactly like the wild ones I have seen, but it's close.

Comment: I'm sticking with Lavatera - the sepals in the picture indicate lavatera rather than alcea.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Could be a Swamp Rose Mallow, a species of Hibiscus. Do the flowers start of light in the morning and darken in colour by noon?